# Fixed Document Tables?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, fixeddocument

I am looking for a layout control or other means of laying out data in a tabular format on a Fixed Document for reporting. I have used MigraDoc quite extensively in non WPF projects and its table object allows for a granular layout for each piece of data to be displayed in the table. Borders can be turned off on the cell level, columns can be merged/spanned, etc. Are there any controls that offer this kind on control within WPF? I have not seen where the DataGrid or the Grid will do what I need... easily. My data is not bound as I need to have full control over how it is displayed. I am not using a flow document so I cannot use the table object that it offers. Anyone have any suggestions? For now, I have resorted to programmatically creating a Grid and then inserting a Border containing a TextBlock within each cell. There just has to be a cleaner way!

BTW - I am looking to use native WPF controls in this project which is the reason that I am not using MigraDoc.

Comment: `There just has to be a cleaner way!` - It's called DataBinding.

Comment: @HighCore, please elaborate... from 10,000 feet, lets say I have a list of datatables, I need to iterate the list and display the data contain in each. Each datatable will vary in column and row count. Each "display" of data needs to be the same width. Depending on the data contained in each datatable cell, column, etc. the display will need to react, background colors, font weights, borders, will need to be changed. Column spans will need to be altered as well. So, what control can I use for this and how should it be bound?